# Global Variable not resetting for each group

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to use a global variable to calculate a bonus. I can get the variable to count correctly with the exception that it is not resetting when changing groups.  I have three groups - Property, Agent, Type.  I have tried to put the reset in every group footer - neither of which are suppressed - and the counting continues.  If I use WhilePrinting/ReadingRecords it works fine but then I cannot use the variable in any formula as I get a "summary has been specified on a non recurring field" error.

Here are some sample codes I am using

@LeaseCount- this is in the detail section

```
EvaluateAfter({@Effective Rent});
global numbervar x;
x:=IIF({@Effective Rent}>={Command.Yieldstar}, x+1, x)
```

@reset_x

```
global numbervar x:= 0;
```

@bonus

```
 IF {@LeaseCount} in 0 TO 6 THEN 50.00
    ELSE IF {@LeaseCount} in 7 TO 11 THEN 80.00
    ELSE IF {@LeaseCount} >= 12 THEN 100.00 ELSE 0.00
 Else 0.00
```

I have the bonus section evaluating after the counter.  Again everything is working just fine except the reset of the variable.  If I try to use a shared variable it breaks with the "non-recurring" error.  I think i have tried everything I can find and at a loss.
I believe it is something to do with timing I am just not well versed with CR timing but then it may just be my coding.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Place the reset variable in header instead of footer..so that for every change of group value is resetted

Comment: The issue was with a summary field in the Agent footer.  After deleting the summary field and moving the variables to SHARED it solved the immediate issue.  I then used another variable to do a running summary instead of a running total summary.

Comment: @siva I had put it in both the header and footer with the same result.

Comment: please answer your question so that others can use :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with a summary field in the Agent footer. After deleting the summary field and moving the variables to SHARED it solved the immediate issue. I then used another variable to do a running summary instead of a running total summary. –

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare it as "shared" instead of "global". Remember to change the declaration in both formulas: @LeaseCount and @reset_x.

If it does not work, try to change @reset_x in two lines:

```
shared numbervar x;
numbervar x:= 0;
```

Comment: Same non-recurring error when attempting to use Shared varaible.